# Restrictions on exporting Reports as .csv

Tags: data-export

When you export data from Salesforce by going to a Report and clicking on "Export Details", then exporting the file as a .csv file, does this "use up" any of the restrictions on a Salesforce account? E.g., contribute towards limits on execution or other usage limits? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , there is no limit on the use up. You can run the report as many times needed and export the details to csv or Excel. However, there is a limit on number of column and records. Thanks

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_export.htm

```
You can export up to 256 columns and 65,536 rows of data in one report.
```